# SQL version of SUMIF

Tags: sql, sum

I want to understand how to code the following SUM calculation for the final column `Total_Concat_Quantity` in the example table below.

Please note that my data set contains thousands of combinations of `Concat` which repeat. I am not looking to remove the duplicates from the data set. I am not looking for a solution that contained hard-coded information - e.g `(SUM(CASE WHEN [Concat] = '201201A' THEN..` as there are too many combinations of `Concat`

```
**TABLE 1** :- Year, Month, YYYYMM, Product, Concat, Quantity, Total_Concat_Quantity

2012 / / JAN / / 201201 / / A / / 201201A / / 11 / / 48
2012 / / JAN / / 201201 / / A / / 201201A / / 37 / / 48
2013 / / JAN / / 201301 / / B / / 201301B / / 19 / / 30
2013 / / JAN / / 201301 / / B / / 201201B / / 11 / / 30
2012 / / FEB/ / 201202 / / C / / 201202C / / 17 / / 17
2012 / / NOV/ / 201211 / / C / / 201211C / / 41 / / 54
2013 / / JAN / / 201301 / / A / / 201301A / / 53 / / 53
2013 / / FEB/ / 201302 / / B / / 201302B / / 47 / / 47
2012 / / NOV/ / 201211 / / C / / 201211C / / 13 / / 54
2013 / / FEB / / 201302 / / A / / 201302A / / 23 / / 23
```

Answer (score 2):

Most versions of SQL support window/analytic functions.  This is the sytnax:

```
select t.*, sum(quantity) over (partition by product) as TotalConcatQuantity
from table t;
```

It is also possible to express this as an aggregation with a join, but window functions are easier to type, clearer, and likely to perform better.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon already mentioned the alternative of a join. It can also be expressed as a correlated subquery if analytic functions aren't available.

```
select *
     , ( select sum(T2.quantity) as Total_Concat_Quantity
         from T as T2 
         where T2.concat = T.concat )
from T
```

The problem with using an explicit join is that the rows in T will be multiplied by the corresponding number of rows with the same concat value. So you then have to do a grouping and aggregation (min or max) to get the single rows with the original values.